# Wifi on\off on Hp Split X13 with Intel 3160 AC

Tags: networking, wireless, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I've tried so many linux distros and versions but the problem with my laptops wifi is always there by default the wireless LED will blink On\OFF and Network Manager reflect this on its menu.

after more than 6 hours of debugging I've found the solution while googling and I wanted to share it ;-D

The problem is that we have a conflicting module being loaded on boot and we need to disable it called acer_wmi
to do this, get a terminal and paste
`sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
enter your password and add the following line to the end of the file
`blacklist acer_wmi`
save and reboot it should work
if it doesn't maybe you have a missing firmware
try form a terminal
`dmesg | grep ".ucode"`
if it returns something note the line.
navigate to 
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi
and download 3160 firmware then extract it and place it in /lib/firmware/
now reboot it should work ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that we have a conflicting module being loaded on boot and we need to disable it called acer_wmi to do this, get a terminal and paste 
`sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` 
enter your password and add the following line to the end of the file `blacklist acer_wmi`
save and reboot it should work if it doesn't maybe you have a missing firmware try form a terminal
`dmesg | grep ".ucode"` 
if it returns something note the line. navigate to `https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi` 
and download 3160 firmware then extract it and place it in /lib/firmware/ now reboot it should work ^_^